# JSONArray returning date as an object?

Tags: java, javascript, json

I am working in web development with java at serverside and javascript at clientside ... i access a java function using post method that returns a json ... while returning i get all the values through a json array but the date fieild is returning as [Object object] ... what to do to convert that object to date ?

```
List<LocateOffice> officeList = commonService.searchoffice(office, company, ocity, state, area);
            request.setAttribute("officeList",officeList);

if(officeList!=null)
            {
                JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject(officeList);
                response.getWriter().print(jsonArray.toString());
            }
```

after that in javascript when i access officelist json using for loop

```
alert(officelist[i].createdDate);
```

this alert returns [Object object]

Update : my question is not about alert() just for ur understanding purpose i entered code like that , wherever i use that json the date is returning an object ... how to convert that object to javascript date or string ...

Comment: can you please share the JSON array.

Comment: It would help to be able to see your code.

Comment: @Mahesh Sapkal I have updated my question

Comment: What is the result of `jsonArray.toString()`?

Comment: Don't use `alert()`, it's not designed for outputting JavaScript objects. Use `console.log()` if you want to see its structure.

Comment: What is the result of JSON.stringify(jsonArray) ?

Comment: Depending on the JSON library you are using, it can output Date object in different manners. Share the library you are using.

Comment: my question is not about alert() just for ur understanding purpose i entered code like that , wherever i use that json the date is returning an object ... how to convert that object to javascript date or string ...

Comment: import net.sf.json.JSONArray;

Comment: @Ree I know your question isn't about alert, but using it doesn't give us any meaningful information. Showing us the output of `console.log` would be much more useful.

Comment: I'm assuming the createdDate referred to in your code is a Java Date object?

Comment: @Funkytown yes ... thats a java date object ... is there any ways to convert that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in incompatible field types in the `List<LocateOffice>`

The `JSONArray.fromObject(Object object)` method will convert your "object" into a `JSONArray` object. The way that method works is by inspecting the types of the objects to be converted. `JSONArray` objects only accept values of type `Boolean`, `JSONArray`, `JSONObject`, `Number`, `String`, or the `JSONNull object`.

`JSONObject` only accept the same types, so I think you'll need to manually go through your list and convert any incompatible objects into a compatible object (e.g. turn your `Date` into a `String` and then put it into the `JSONArray`).

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks friend ... ya i did the same what u said b4 seeing ur answer ... i hope there ll be some other way to convert date object ... anyway thanks for ur support ...